# Trigonometric substitution

Tags: trigonometry

Been out of touch with trigonometry for some time now. Need help proving this expression.

$$\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos\left(x\right))$$

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is outright rude, I post my first question and get a down vote. If you can't help, just move on.

Comment: did you mean $\frac{\sin^2(x)}2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos^2(x))$

Comment: @ParthKohli,nope I meant what I wrote

Comment: Oh, x^2/2 is the angle.  OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ and $\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$, rewrite the LHS as
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)-\left(\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)-\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)\right)\\
&=\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)
\end{align}
$$

---

$$\color{blue}{\Large\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 1) $\cos(2a)=\cos(a+a)=2\cos^2(a)-1=1-2\sin^2(a)$ (using $\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)=1$). Now use the result with $a=x/2$.